# nlohmann json: securely erase the keys (C++)

Tags: c++, security, memset, nlohmann-json, securezeromemory

I'm using [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library to represent sensitive information. Once the needed processing has been completed, I'm interested in securely erasing the **keys** of the `json` type.

Example:

```
json test;
test["key1"] = "value1";
test["key2"] = "value2";

for (auto item = test.begin(); item != test.end(); ++item) {
    // Processing going on here
    // Let's print this information to simulate that it's "used"
    // In the real application no data is printed / stored here,
    // just processed.
    std::cout << item.value().dump();
    std::cout << item.key().dump();
    // This particular key is not needed anymore here
}

// Keys are not needed here. How can I be sure 
// that "key1" and "key2" are guaranteed 
// not present in memory in any shape or form?

// Will this achieve my goal?
test.erase(test.begin(), test.end());
```

The result I'm trying to achieve is similar to what can be accomplished with the [memset_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) method or [SecureZeroMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa366877(v=vs.85)) on Microsoft platform.

Alternatively, a string contents can be replaced with some arbitrary information with the help of the [std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) algorithm:

```
std::fill(string.begin(), string.end(), 0);
```

My question is, **would the proposed approach of calling `erase` on the `json` completely remove the keys from the memory, or is there a chance that contents of those strings still will be present in the memory?**

Comment: Just a couple of notes: It doesn't matter if you print the secret information to a terminal or write to a file, it will probably stay in in-memory buffers for a while. And unless you write to an encrypted file (or filesystem) then the data will also be available in plain-text on disk. Lastly, security through obscurity only makes life harder for the programmers and users, and almost never for potential "hackers".

Comment: Printing sensitive information to a terminal is added just as a reference that the information is used in some way in that loop. It is obviously not printed nor written to a file.